# "No module named 'twilio.rest' ; twilio is not a package"

Tags: python-3.x, twilio

When I run this code in anaconda prompt it works properly and sends message, but in editor I get error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'twilio.rest'; 'twilio' is not a package"

```
from twilio.rest import Client
account_sid = "ACXXXXXXX"
auth_token  = "XXXXXXXX"
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
message = client.messages.create(to="+916573864710", 
from_="+1469347379",body="hey code run without any errors!")
print(message.sid)
```

Comment: Did you name your script `twilio.py` perhaps? You can't re-use top-level library names for scripts.

Comment: Hey Martijn Pieters thank you, its working now after renaming.